# JqGrid keyboard navigation

Tags: jqgrid

I have an editable Jqgrid(where when im clicking on a row, that row get editable) with 3 dropdown lists in it, what i want is:

1. when im clicking on a row, its get editable and selects first dropdown in a row
2. after i choosed an object in dropdown list and pressed tab it jumps to the next dropdown (already happends)
3. same as the 2. but it have to jump to the third dropdown list
4. when im done editing, when i press down key or just press somewhere else on the screen data which i edited should be saved to DB. so it have to happend withount me pressing enter key, which i have to do now.
5. if i press down key, selection have to jump down to next row and save the previouse row which i just edited

I know its a long one, but i cant get path keyboard selection because im stuck with clickable edit....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `multiselect:true` you can use [bindKeys](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method to have keyboard support.

If you need to change the order of focus on <kbd>Tab</kbd> pressing you can change `tabindex` attribute on the editable fields (input or select elements). You can use `oneditfunc` parameter of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) for such initialization actions.